# Starting route on pgrouting from coordinate that is not node

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, osm2pgrouting

After execute all steps from this [pgRouting](http://download.osgeo.org/pgrouting/foss4g2010/workshop/docs/html/chapters/introduction.html) tutorial, now I have a map that creates and displays routes, but as the routing methods rely on parameters representing vertex Ids that was created using osm2pgrouting, my route always starts either after or before the place I selected on the map, and ends on the same way.. after or before the place it should end.

There are tools that are based on pgrouting, that displays the route ending and starting exactly where the user clicked, not in the nearest node.

Is there a way to create more nodes between the current ones, so I would reduce the distance between nodes to few meters, what would fix it, or if there is another solution to my issue?

Comment: You need use tsrp, as suggested by amball, support offset on the edge. http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/152145/22366